# Using javascript/jquery variables inside blade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use javascript variables inside laravel blade.

But I'm getting this error.

What should I do for using this ?

```
var activeTab = $("ul#tablist li.active");
var floor = {!! \App\Floor::find(activeTab.attr('id')) !!}
```

> Use of undefined constant activeTab - assumed 'activeTab'

Comment: Get the floor you want with an ajax call to your back-end. You should not be trying to mix php with jquery this way.

Comment: `$("ul#tablist li.active")` isn't javascript. It's a JQuery selector ...

Comment: do you warp javascript inside your <script> tag ? If you give more blade  source it will easy to inspect what is going wrong.

Comment: Just use `var floor = activeTab.attr('id');`

Comment: actually problem I can get id wtih var floor = activeTab.attr('id'); but I need the get object using id

Comment: DOING BIG MISTAKE!!! : You cannot pass immediately  javascript data as a parameter to php functions.

Comment: @suresh what should I do to get this object ?

Comment: You can try with ajax based implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you can have another route like this:

```
    Route::post('/getFloorById', [
        'uses'  => 'YourController@getFloorById',
        'as'    => 'getFloorById'
    ]);
```

Then, in you controller you have the method:

```
private function getFloorById($segments)
{
    $floorId = $segments[1];
    return \App\Floor::find($floorId);
}
```

And last, you need your javascript code:

```
var floor = $.post('/getFloorById', {"id": activeTab.attr('id')});
```

This is the ajax method. Keep in mind that you might need to use `echo` instead of a `return`. And you might need to wrap your code into `json_encode(\App\Floor::find($floorId))` like this, but for the most part this should get the job done.

You might want to call the post from an `onclick` event that way you get the new object every time the tab changes.

Comment: Thanks I'm using like this way

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately blade is just a framework to output php. You don't need to do that, and you won't be able to anyways. That would be a big security issue.

If you really need that `floor` use what @Rohan suggested, javascript directly:

```
var floor = activeTab.attr('id');
```

Comment: actually problem I can get id wtih var floor = activeTab.attr('id'); but I need the get object using id

Comment: if there's no way you can get `id` before the DOM renders, you need to use ajax and make a call to a php script with the `activeTab.attr('id')` as a param

Comment: might be easier to just explain what you want to do exactly as what you're trying to do above is just not possible.

Comment: Actually I need the get active tab and use get the floor object dynamically. Also there was a socket connection which is recieving data every second I need the check it is correct and take the action

Comment: The easiest way I can see, I might be wrong as I'm not fully understanding your code without having a look at it, but you could grab everything from the  Floor `\App\Floor::findAll` (or something like that) and store it as an object variable in javascript... then you can just use the id to grab whichever you need

Comment: actually I just need the use activeTab.attr('id') in \App\Floor::find(activeTab.attr('id')) like this

Comment: As I mentioned that's not possible... you're in php there and `activeTab.attr('id')` is javascript. You have 2 options: 1. use ajax; 2. save the object from a `findAll` function and use the id later to grab what you're looking for